# How to relocate a VBox inside a StackPane

Tags: java, javafx, layout

I wish a vertical time mark follow the mouse over several chronograms to indicate a time stamp but setLayoutX() or relocate() has no effect at all on StackPane.

I wrote the following minimal reproducible example:

```
public class VerticalTimeMarkIsNotRelocated extends Application {

   @FXML private StackPane timeMarkContainer;
   @FXML private Label     label;
   @FXML private VBox      timeMark;

   @FXML
   private void initialize() {
      StackPane.clearConstraints( timeMark );
      StackPane.setAlignment( label, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER );
   }

   @FXML
   private void moveTimeMark( MouseEvent e ) {
      final double x = e.getX();
      System.err.printf( "%7.2f\n", x );
      timeMark.relocate( x, 0 );
   }

   @Override
   public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {
      final Class<?> clazz = getClass();
      primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( FXMLLoader.load( clazz.getResource( clazz.getSimpleName() + ".fxml" ))));
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      launch( args );
   }
}
```

VerticalTimeMarkIsNotRelocated.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="so.VerticalTimeMarkIsNotRelocated"
   fx:id="timeMarkContainer" prefWidth="420" prefHeight="140" onMouseMoved="#moveTimeMark">
   <stylesheets>
      <URL value="@VerticalTimeMarkIsNotRelocated.css" />
   </stylesheets>
   <Label fx:id="label" text="Replacement for several chronogram widgets" />
   <VBox  fx:id="timeMark" minWidth="1.0" maxWidth="1.0" />
</StackPane>
```

VerticalTimeMarkIsNotRelocated.css:

```
#timeMark {
  -fx-background-color: red;
}
#label {
  -fx-background-color: bisque;
  -fx-padding: 40px;
}
```

On the following screen snapshot, we can see in the Eclipse console that the mouse move but the vertical red mark is still located in the middle of the StackPane:

[image: Vertical time mark is not relocated]

Comment: basically, you are fighting the layout (and tricksing it into doing as you want to by mis-using the margin is .. evil ;) - locating a managed child by some external code will be reverted on every layout pass.

Comment: You seem to have `Controller` code in the class that extends `Application`.

Comment: @kleopatra: which layout is better to use?

Answer (score 1):

Set Margin Programmatically and use
Insets(double top, double right, double bottom, double left)

```
   @FXML
   private void moveTimeMark( MouseEvent e ) {
      final double x = e.getX();
      System.err.printf( "%7.2f\n", x );
      StackPane.setMargin(timeMark, new Insets(0,x,0,0));
   }
```

Comment: No it doesn't answer the problem. Run it.

Answer (score 0):

setMargin resolve the problem with a small calculus:

```
@FXML
private void moveTimeMark( MouseEvent e ) {
   StackPane.setMargin( timeMark,
      new Insets( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -timeMarkContainer.getWidth()+2.0*e.getX()));
}
```

Why this calculus is needed?